# What happened to MVCContrib Subcontrollers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I see several articles on the interwebs about MVCContrib's subcontroller feature, but I don't see anything on the codeplex site about it.

Has this feature been supplanted by something in MVC2?

Whats the best approach for rendering controls with their own data pipeline (submit to their own controller, display data from their own controller) in MVC?

Comment: Check out this article http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC2 Beta has Html.RenderAction, which allows you to call "children" actions - I believe this is pretty much the same as MVCContrib's subcontrollers.

(see http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx for details)